# Ubuntu python import tensorflow error with sudo

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow, cuda, sudo

I installed cuda, cudnn and tensorflow-gpu successfully,
I run

`python3 
import tensorflow`

this worked fine, but I can't import tensorflow with sudo:

`sudo python3
import tensorflow`

I got :

`ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So what's the problem and how to deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you installed cuda, cudnn and tensorflow-gpu with a virtual env or pip and the files are in your personal path and not in the system?  Maybe the root user has a different copy of python earlier in the path?  Do ``python -V`` as yourself and also ``sudo python -V``

Comment: I installed tensorflow-gpu with pip3 and `python -V` version was same with `sudo python -V` @Vorsprung

Comment: As a workaround you could ``sudo pip install cuda  cudnn tensorflow-gpu``

Answer (score 4):

I found the environment variables of common command was different with environment variablese of sudo, and I fix this problem by adding CUDA paths to the sudo Environment variables:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc`. then `source ~/.bashrc`